# Using the word 'alexa' in SSML audio

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ssml

I have implemented a skill that plays short SSML audio clips.

However, a few of the audio clips have alexa phrase suggestions in them.

One of the clips includes the phrase 'alexa stop'.

To my surprise it looks as if alexa 'listens' to itself in this scenario as the skill then exits instead of following the intended workflow.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mangle the word "Alexa" until it's no longer recognized--but it's possible that this will change in the future and start to be recognized again. Generally the suggestion is to not use the word "Alexa" in a response at all, what is your goal for including this phrase?